# Find 15 minutes time interval from a column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make 15 minutes time interval from a column using sql using below query:

```
Select from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(InitiatedDateTimeGmt, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')),'yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss'))/(15*60))*(15*60)) GroupTime,
COUNT(*) as Cnt
FROM Chat
GROUP BY GroupTime order by 1
```

where InitiatedDateTimeGmt is a column name in timestamp format like 2021-01-04 00:00:00.

But i am getting many values as null.

Example:

| GroupTime | Cnt |
| --- | --- |
| null | 335783 |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 68 |
| 2021-01-04 00:15:00 | 81 |
| 2021-01-04 00:30:00 | 74 |
| 2021-01-04 00:45:00 | 81 |
| 2021-01-04 01:00:00 | 94 |
| 2021-01-04 01:15:00 | 98 |

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What’s the output of `select count(*) from Chat where InitiatedDateTimeGmt is null`?

Comment: There is no null values in that

Comment: Do you just know that, or did you run the query and get `0`?

Comment: I have run the query also Sir

Comment: please add some data to your exampole output to make [mre]

Comment: @Akshay please edit your question to provide the query you are actually running; the one you show has an invalid second parameter to unix_timestamp   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=eec036024ed49d8c7545c4b67fa72a21

Comment: This query run fine in databricks

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Means. Please explain

Comment: I'm asking you to try running the query `select version();` and tell us what it shows.

Comment: 3.0.1000000 it is showing

Comment: I'm removing the mysql tag; this isn't mysql

Comment: It is resolved by using below query: Select from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(InitiatedDateTimeGmt, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))/(15*60))*(15*60)) GroupTime,
COUNT(*) as Cnt
FROM Chat
GROUP BY GroupTime order by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved by using below query:

```
    Select from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(InitiatedDateTimeGmt, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))/(15*60))*(15*60)) GroupTime, COUNT(*) as Cnt FROM Chat GROUP BY GroupTime order by 1
```

Comment: If you don't need the date formatting, a simplified version is: `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(InitiatedDateTimeGmt)/(15*60))*(15*60)) AS GroupTime, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Chat GROUP BY GroupTime order by 1`